# Shiny R issues when selecting and calculating

Tags: r, shiny, event-handling

I'm having some trouble with a modular shiny app I'm building. In the module in question, I'm trying to give the user the ability to calculate changes between two dates and having them display in a couple of charts & reactables.

Here is the code:

```
calcChangesModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h4("Choose dates here:"),
        selectInput(ns("date_start"), "Select start", choices = NULL),
        selectInput(ns("date_end"), "Select end", choices = NULL),
        actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.submit == 0",
          h4("Choose and start and end, then hit 'Submit'")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.submit > 0",
          hr(),
          h4("Factors"),
          plotlyOutput(ns("chart1")),
          hr(),
          h3("Drivers"),
          reactableOutput(ns("summary_table")),
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

calcChangesModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- readRDS("C:/A_place/lots_of_data.RDS")
 
  selectable_dates <- reactive({
    dates_from_data <- unique(data[["Pretty Consistent Dataset"]]$Date)
    dates_from_data
  })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "date_start", choices = selectable_dates())
    updateSelectInput(session, "date_end", choices = selectable_dates())
  })

observeEvent(input$submit, {
    date1 <- input$date_start
    date2 <- input$date_end
    req(date1, date2)
    print(date1)
    print(date2)
    if(!is.null(date1) && !is.null(date2)){
      print("Inside the conditional block")
    # loads and loads of calculations
    # followed quickly by reactable and plotlys

})
}
```

While the conditionalPanel()s work as expected, the observeEvent() doesn't appear to fire at all (I've also tried with eventReactive) - it neither prints date1 or date2, nor does it print the "Inside the conditional block"; why might this be?

### Edit

Added 'actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")', sadly the conditionals no longer work.

Comment: `actionButton(("submit"), "Submit")` is missing `ns`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, though sadly the conditionalPanels no longer work - does print the print("Inside the conditional block") now though

Comment: @alec22 See `?conditionalPanel`. There is an option to include the `ns`.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding: actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")

And:
ns = ns in the conditionalPanel()s